# ¿Cómo se puede acceder a TSearchResult cuando usamos TDirectory.GetDirectories / TDirectory.GetFileSystemEntries

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Estoy usando Delphi 2010. Sé perfectamente cómo se usa FirdFirst, FindNext, FindClose y al mismo tiempo acceder al registro TSearchResult. Recientmente vi un ejemplo de TDirectory en IOUtils y veo que es más fácil de programar (GetDirectories, GetFileSystemEntries y TFilterPredicate), pero no veo cómo puedo obtener la información que antes me daba TSearchResult (Name, Size, Date, Attr...). Agradecería la ayuda, un enlace a un ejemplo me sirve igualmente. ¡Gracias anticipadas!

Comment: Hermano traduce por favor, estás en la versión hispana de StackOverflow :D

Comment: Bienvenido podrias editar tu pregunta que el idioma oficial es el español

Comment: Pido disculpas a todos, entré a StackOverFlow desde una búsqueda en inglés, y nunca me di cuenta del cambio al español cuando me registré. Para mí es una bendición, el inglés me mata!

Answer (score 0):

Todo lo que necesitas está en las units `System.IOUtils` y `System.Types`.

Si utilizas la función `GetFiles` que comentas, puedes recupoerar de forma fácil los nombres ficheros a partir de un path.
Una vez que obtienes la lista de ficheros, individualmente puedes acceder a cada fichero utilizando el record `TFile`, definido en la misma unit.

Utilizando `TFile` puedes acceder a los atributos del fichero y a otras operaciones. 
Aquí tienes un ejemplo de utilización:

```
var
  lFiles:TStringDynArray;
  i, j:integer;
  sPath:String;
  lAttributes:TFileAttributes;
begin

  lFiles := TDirectory.GetFiles('c:\temp\', '*.*', TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
  for i := 0 to Length(lFiles) - 1 do begin
    sPath := lFiles[i];
    if TFile.Exists(sPath) then begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(sPath);
      // Atributos de TFile.
      lAttributes := TFile.GetAttributes(sPath);
      // Algunos atributos...
      if (TFileAttribute.faReadOnly in lAttributes) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add('      -> Sólo lectura');
      if (TFileAttribute.faDirectory in lAttributes) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add('      -> Directorio');
      if (TFileAttribute.faSystem in lAttributes) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add('      -> Sistema');
      if (TFileAttribute.faArchive in lAttributes) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add('      -> Archivo');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Creo que no expliqué con claridad la información a la que yo deseo acceder. Se trata de obtener **la misma** información que nos devuelve 'TSearchRec' cuando se usan las rutinas 'FindFirst' y 'FindNext'. Su ejemplo me enseña a obtener **una parte**, que sería 'TSearchRec.Attr', pero yo querría acceder, además, a 'TSearchRec.Time' y TSearchRec.Size'.
Aprovecho para indicarle que el _copia y pega_ le ha jugado una mala pasada, que quizá algún lector poco iniciado no sepa detectar.

Comment: El código que te puse era de ejemplo para que vieras cómo se utiliza para obtener algunos datos. `TFile` tiene más métodos y basta con mirar la unit para ver cuales son.
En cuanto a los que pides, pues el tema de fechas sí que puedes obtenerlo, utilizando métodos como `GetLastAccessTime`, `GetLastWriteTime`, `GetCreationTime`,...  El cuando al tamaño del fichero no está disponible y tendrás que calcularlo de otra forma.

Comment: @L.Alfredo  
En cuanto a lo que comentas del Copy&Paste, si explicas cual es el problema podré corregirlo. Es un código copiado de un proyecto de ejempo (que yo mismo he realizado), funciona perfectamente en Delphi XE7 que es con la versión con la que lo he hecho.

Comment: Actualizo mi anterior respuesta. Después de mucho ensayo y error, he conseguido algo extraño. El compilador acepta:  
`  dFileDate := TDirectory.GetCreationTime( sPath );`   
donde `dFileDate` es una variable de tipo `DateTime`. Pero al ejecutarlo, aparece el error _EDirectoryNotFoundException_ a pesar de haber pasado la verificación   `If TFile.Exists(sPath)`

Comment: Ahora lo sorprendente: si detengo la ejecución en la línea de error (de la respuesta anterior), pulso Ctrl+F7, introduzo `TDirectory.DoGetCreationTime(sPath)` el depurador me devuelve la información de fecha y hora de creación. Pero si introduzco   
`dFileDate := TDirectory.DoGetCreationTime(sPath)`  
 en el código, el compilador dice _[Error] E2361 Cannot access private symbol TDirectory.DoGetCreationTime_

Comment: *Copia y pega*, respuesta para @Germán Estévez -Neftalí-: en mi _muy humilde opinión_, debería ser (líneas 18~21):  
  `If (TFileAttribute.faDirectory in lAttributes) then Memo1.Lines.Add(' -> Directorio');   If (TFileAttribute.faSystem in lAttributes) then Memo1.Lines.Add(' -> Sistema');`  
Y 'merci beaucoup!' por toda su ayuda.

Comment: @L.Alfredo Tienes toda la razón en lo del `Copy&Paste`, error al generar el código. Lo corrijo.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la fecha, declaras la variable `dFileDate` como `TDateTime`, y añades esto a tu código:

```
   dFileDate := TFile.GetCreationTime( sPath );
```

En cuanto al tamaño usando `TFile`, no tengo ni idea. Hay otras soluciones sin tener que usar `FileSize`, pero no es lo que preguntas.

Comment: No sé por qué las normas del foro impiden decir "gracias", así que te digo _"Thank you so much!"_